# Import 2 JavaScript functions with the same name in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular

I imported JavaScript files into Angular project like this: https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular

It's all working fine. However, there is one problem. I have 2 JavaScript files that I imported that have the same name. So, when I use it in my component's typescript like this:

```
declare const CMenu: any
```

there is a name collision between those 2 functions.

Is there a way to import JavaScript files, just for one particular Angular module. For example, to specify in Angular.json in which module to import the JavaScript file. I actually have a lot of JS files that use same function names, and I need to use those from 2 different modules (each module using different function with the same name).

Answer (score 1):

You can import it with an alias on the page where you need it.

```
 import CMenu as CeeMenu from 'locationA';
 import CMenu as CMenu from 'locationB';

 declare const a:CeeMenu;
 declare const b:CMenu;
```

These imports can be joined in one file, exporting them with an alias, hence you can import them from one location.

```
 import CMenu as CeeMenu from 'locationA';
 import CMenu as CMenu from 'locationB';
 export CeeMenu as AA, CMenu as BB;
```

then

```
 import AA, BB from 'locationC';
 declare const a:AA;
 declare const b:BB;
```

Comment: when I try to use import like this: "import CMain as CMain from '/../../externalJS/Cmain.js'" I got an error "Cannot find namespace 'as'"